# Creating a new page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I'm trying to create a new page to my module without success. I have created a module with the contents:

> app\code\local\CompanyName\Insignias\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_Insignias>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </CompanyName_Insignias>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <insignias>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>CompanyName_Insignias</module>
                    <frontName>insignias</frontName>
                </args>
            </insignias>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <insignias>
                    <file>insignias.xml</file>
                </insignias>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
  <...>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\CompanyName\Insignias\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php

class CompanyName_Insignias_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

and

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/insignias.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <insignias_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="insignias/index" name="insignias_index" template="insignias/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </insignias_index_index>
</layout>
```

I have created the index.phtml file at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/insignias/index.phtml with a `<?php echo "worked" ?>` to test it, but when I try to access domain/index.php/insignias it shows me all the default magento blocks, but without my echo content, just a blank page in the content

Can someone help me?

edit:

[image]

Comment: Is it showing blank page or 404 not found page?
can you please send screenshot?

Comment: just a blank page

Comment: can you send a screenshot of that page so that I can check.

Comment: just edited the content

Comment: please check system.log file under var/log folder. I think you will get error there. If not then enable developer mode and check log file again

Comment: You are right, I got the following error:
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Insignias_Block_Index' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NetBeansProjects/magento9/app/Mage.php:595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you didn't created Block file and mentioned block name in your .xml file.

```
<reference name="content">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>insignias/index.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

try this without block in your xml. 
hope this helps.

Comment: I did it here:

<reference name="content">
      <block type="insignias/index" name="insignias_index" template="insignias/index.phtml" />
    </reference>

Comment: did you create Block file inside block folder and mentioned block inside config.xml file? Once you did this then your code should work as expected.

Comment: no problem.. Happy Coding :)